# Why does Ruby use the '=>' notation?

Tags: ruby, hashrocket

Where did it come from?

Why didn't they use `->` or some other notation?

Comment: Because with '->' it could only be monorails! ..er...sorry.

Comment: Why would it? If you have problems with => be happy that you can now do {sym: 1} instead of {:sym => 1}

Comment: Oh my god rjz. I think I love you.

Comment: The `=>` notation most likely came from Perl's "fat comma" (also `=>`), they're both used for the same thing. But this isn't the right place for questions like this.

Comment: @ismaelga: But the JavaScript style isn't always an option, Hashes can have any objects as keys and if you're going to use MongoDB you'll have to use `=>` for things like `:$set => { ... }` as `$set: { ... }` is a syntax error.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, it's not always possible, but in most cases when you need to represent a Hash in code you use symbols. And thanks, I didn't know about that detail on MongoDB, haven't tried yet with ruby.

Comment: Indeed I think it's from Perl as mu is too short write, and I think that is for visual appearance. `=>` looks more like an arrow than `->`.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for your comment, but what's the rationale? So long as this answer is about programming rather than programmers, and has an objective answer, I don't see why it shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: This doesn't seem to fall under "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face" and "not constructive" seemed like the closest match. I don't think SO is the right place for this sort of thing, a Ruby mailing list would be better and four other people agreed with me. I did offer the most likely answer as well as voting to close (which I do a fair bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faster interpreting. The => is not ever going to be used anywhere else, -> may be, making it quicker to decide what to do with as you parse the script.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is the reason? The comment about Perl seems much more probable.

Answer (score 3):

So when they use `->`, will you ask why does Rails(actually not Rails bu Ruby) use `->`, and why not `=>`?

By the way, the new lambda syntax in Ruby 1.9 use `->`.